# Error handling with Azure Function ServiceBusTrigger

Tags: c#, error-handling, azure-functions, try-catch

I have an Azure Function as below. I came to know that `ServiceBusTrigger` provides a retry mechanism and by default retry `five times` and after that write a message to a `poison queue`. In this case, how to handle errors that comes within function context?

e.g. In the following code, I'm adding a product to the database and I want to handle errors for that code block using `Try-Catch`. Is it a better way? will it affect the standard retry mechanism? please advice.

```
[FunctionName("SaveProductData")]
public void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("mytopicname", Connection = "ServiceBusConnectionString")]
ProductItemUpdate message, ILogger log)
{
    var product = new Domain.Entities.Product()
    {
       ... prop init goes here..... 
    };

    log.LogInformation($"Processed Product - Sain: {message.ProductId}");
    _productRepository.Add(product);
 }
```

Comment: A retry policy is evaluated whenever an execution results in an uncaught exception. As a best practice, you should catch all exceptions in your code and rethrow any errors that should result in a retry. - From MS [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-error-pages?tabs=csharp).

Comment: You can do the usual data validations and try to insert your product into database inside a `try..catch` block, on receiving any SqlException, you can log error message in your log source, and complete the function without rethrowing it. Azure will do retry only if your code did not complete correctly and did not handle the exception.

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran you mean to say just a LogError like this `log.LogError($"Error : {e.Message}");` without rethrow

Comment: If your database insertion failed due to some business logic checks, or any SQL constraint violation, then there is no point in retrying to process the message. You need to decide where you want to log errors when you process messages, the simple ILogger only writes those errors in App Insights, upto you to inform your application and eventually the `end user` (if any)

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran For example, if I have 10 messages in Service Bus Queue, I got an SQL error while processing 3rd message. In this case, I can log the message for a later process and continue with the 4th message, and so on. So we need to rethrow here right?

Comment: If you rethrow, then that 3rd message will be retried - do you want that - will the error go away when retry is made, think about it. Also, since it is a trigger, there is no guarantee that Azure will do FIFO message processing unless you are using session or partitioned queues. Azure can even invoke your trigger functions simultaneously for those 10 queue messages.

Comment: Message retry is useful and applicable only for transient errors, see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-messaging-exceptions) page to understand for which type of scenarios retry makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Anand Sowmithran. Posting your valuable suggestions as an answer to help other community members.

SQL Exceptions can be logged in the log source using simple `ILogger` that will write in App Insights.

For SQL constraint violation, Retry Mechanism is not useful. Azure will do retry only if your code fails to complete its functionality.

> A retry policy is evaluated whenever an execution results in an uncaught exception. As a best practice, you should catch all exceptions in your code and rethrow any errors that should result in a retry. - From MS [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-error-pages?tabs=csharp).

> Message retry is useful and applicable only for transient errors, see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-messaging-exceptions) page to understand for which type of scenarios retry makes sense.